# Why bother building model classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Why not using the map of json key, value instead of building model class and all methods needed to convert from and to json for every http response out there. I think without models changes will be easier to code.

Comment: `Map`s can store heterogeneous data only if you give up type-safety.  If you want both, you should use a class.

Comment: Have a read of the official documentation - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json